# How to add background color to div when radion button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want, when radio button is in the checked state, a div will take a different background color. It should seem as if the whole div is selected when the radio is checked.

When radio button, inside the .pricing-option.one, is checked, .pricing-option.one will take background color. And checked when inside the .pricing-option.two, .pricing-option.two will take background color and same as the rest.

Like the image:

[image]

I don't understand how to do this, can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```html
<div class="visible-xs mobile-pricing-table clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option one text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>50</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>17%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€114.99</strike>
            <h2>€14.99</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">
            <label for="optionsRadios4"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option two text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>200</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>68%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€126.40</strike>
            <h2>€26.40</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5">
            <label for="optionsRadios5"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option three text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>400</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>87%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€149.9</strike>
            <h2>€49.9</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios6" value="option6">
            <label for="optionsRadios6"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I understood this wrong. You're trying to change the color of a tr upon clicking a child radio button. What are the div's for? Slighlty modified the js from JG Estevez and it worked.

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
  var selectedElement=$(this);
  $('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#fff');
  });
  selectedElement.closest('tr').css('background','coral');
});
```

[First row highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QBgo.png)

Comment: Hi. togorks. It seems you checked my code... and I messed up something....

I have made 2 pricing table....one for desktop view and another for mobile view. The above code is for mobile view. And yes, also I am trying to change the color of a tr upon clicking a child radio button.

But I thought if I could figured it out the function...I can do that for desktop pricing table also. Hope you understand.

Your code is working like a charm for the desktop table :D Now I am researching the code and trying to do that for mobile view also.

Thanks you very much for your help :)

Comment: Yesss...Its now workinf for both mobile and desktop pricing table :D
Check it out >> http://shamsulsujon.com/demos/icelotto/

Answer (score 2):

you could use the empty `<label>` right behind the radio button and draw a bg-color from it with selector : `:checked + label`

it involves : `position:relative` + `absolute`, coordonates and `z-index`, and works if column has no background, if it does, all children will require a relative positionning too and a positive z-index, in this case  no z-index are required for the label.

Demo below in snippet, click the radio button to add a bg-color :)

```css
.pricing-option {
  position:relative;/* this tells absolute children where it stands */
  }
:checked + label {
  position:absolute;
  /* coordonates to reach each sides of the relative parent container */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:-1;/* put it underneath the container */
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="">
    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option one text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>50</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>17%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€114.99</strike>
            <h2>€14.99</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">
            <label for="optionsRadios4"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option two text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>200</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>68%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€126.40</strike>
            <h2>€26.40</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5">
            <label for="optionsRadios5"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option three text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>400</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>87%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€149.9</strike>
            <h2>€49.9</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios6" value="option6">
            <label for="optionsRadios6"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## edit

since `<label>` seems already used for another purpose, lets add an empty tag to still avoid javascript:

```css
.pricing-option {
  position:relative;/* this tells absolute children where it stands */
  }
:checked ~ .bg {
  position:absolute;
  /* coordonates to reach each sides of the relative parent container */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:-1;/* put it underneath the container */
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="">
    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option one text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>50</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>17%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€114.99</strike>
            <h2>€14.99</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">
            <label for="optionsRadios4"></label>
          <i class="bg"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option two text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>200</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>68%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€126.40</strike>
            <h2>€26.40</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5">
            <label for="optionsRadios5"></label>
          <i class="bg"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-option three text-center">
        <div class="ticket-quantity">
            <h2>400</h2>
            <p>Lottery Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winning-chances">
            <h2>87%</h2>
            <p>Winning Chances</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <strike>€149.9</strike>
            <h2>€49.9</h2>
            <p>You save 100€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-selection">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios6" value="option6">
            <label for="optionsRadios6"></label>
          <i class="bg"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the empty label for custom radio button style. So I think this way won't help to this problem. However, Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @ShamsulIslamSujon okay, is the label positionned and has it  still a pseudo free to use ? ---  else , if this way suits you, just insert any empty tag (span, i, i , whatever ). ----  the technic only require a tag after the input that is a label or anything else doesn't matter than can be selected via + or ~

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, I haven' tested it but the idea is that when you check any radio button then change the color of **all** the containers to the non selected background color, then just change the containter of the radio button to the selected background color.

```
 $('input:radio').change(
          var selectedElement=$(this);
          $('.pricing-option').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background','yournonselectedcolor');
          });
          selectedElement.closest('.pricing-option').css('background','yourcolorhere');
        );
```

Comment: I have tried this...But it changed nothing.
This is the live page http://shamsulsujon.com/demos/icelotto/

Can you please look at this?

You can also download the whole file from here http://shamsulsujon.com/demos/icelotto.rar

I will be thankful to you if you solve this problem :)